# weblogic 12.2.1.4 cannot compile jsp The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: jsp, compilation, weblogic12c

I have a huge JSP that is working fine on WebLogic version 12.2.1.0.0 but fails on the latest version of WebLogic 12.2.1.4.0. 
Getting the below error _jspService is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
I have compared the parsed java files of both JSP, in the new version, each tag in the java file has try block, which is increasing the size of the function __jspService.

Is there any workaround other than refactoring the JSP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to bypass the 64k limit, as it is as per Java specification and no option available to by pass it. You can try to refactor the problematic JSP or even divide it into smaller JSPs.